# Query is too complex. How to modify query?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

Some where in the application there is an autogenerated query like

```
SELECT DISTINCT `Name`,`Number` 
FROM `Table` 
WHERE (`ID`=@NAZ_ID_0)   
   OR (`ID`=@NAZ_ID_1) 
   OR (`ID`=@NAZ_ID_2)
   OR (`ID`=@NAZ_ID_3) 
   ... 
   OR (`ID`=@NAZ_ID_690)
```

While executing this query ms access throws out exception "Query is too complex". Obviously  because of number of `OR`s which is limited to 99 in ms access.
How to change this query and avoid using this `OR` ... `OR` ... `OR` construction?

Comment: What are these? 700 parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can influence the query creation yourself you can simply use

```
    SELECT DISTINCT `Name`,`Number` FROM `Table` WHERE `ID` IN (@NAZ_ID_0,@NAZ_ID_1,etc)
```

If you can't control the creation of the query, but can alter it before it's used, you can try and replace the or-s with the in-variant.
Finally, if the IN() is also too complex, you might consider creating a temporary table, fill it with the variables and use a subquery in the original query.

Comment: Is there another limit for the number of these IN parameters ?

Comment: @Ask to be honest I'm not sure if there is a limit to the parameters themselves in the oledb provider, but there shouldn't be for the amount of elements in the in-statement itself. Of course there's always the maximum query length to consider, which is about 64.000 characters. If you hit that max, you'll have to use an alternative such as a temporary table.

Answer (score 4):

Under "big" DBMSes, the usual way of solving these kinds of problems is to create a temporary table, and rewrite the query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `Name`,`Number` FROM `Table`
WHERE `ID` IN (SELECT `ID` FROM TemporaryTable)
```

So, instead of assigning bound parameters `@NAZ_ID_X`, simply insert these same values to the temporary table before executing the query.

Also, this makes it easier to avoid dynamically constructing the SQL text and reap the benefits of query [preparation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Unfortunately, Access doesn't directly support temporary tables, so if there are multiple concurrent clients working on the same database, you'll have to generate a **uniquely-named** temporary table for each of them (and adjust the query accordingly).